# Open a new file in VS Code with contents

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, command-line-interface

I want to get some text from the output of a shell command and then open `code` to a new file with that contents.

My first attempt was to pipe the output directly into `code`, but this didn't work.

```sh
echo foo | code
```

My current "solution" is to redirect the output to a `tmp` file, open `tmp` in `code`, and then delete `tmp`.

```sh
echo foo > tmp; code tmp; rm tmp
```

This is tedious and has the ugly effect of showing that the file has been deleted in the tab:

[image: deleted tmp file]

There must be a better way.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out there is!  It's an advanced technique I like to call *Reading the Error Message*™.  ‍♀️

> ```sh
> echo foo | code
> ```
>
> ```
> Run with 'code -' to read output from another program (e.g. 'echo Hello World | code -').
> ```

The solution:

```sh
echo foo | code -
```

Stack Overflow, you truly are the best [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).
Relevant: [Stack Exchange has been taken over by a rubber duck!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308564/stack-exchange-has-been-taken-over-by-a-rubber-duck)

Comment: I've avoided signing into anything personal on my work laptop for a couple of years.  Every time I try to vote, comment, ask, or answer while I'm working, I have to fight myself to not do so.
I have logged in, on my work laptop, just to upvote this question and answer.  I don't like getting error messages, so I search instead of trying 9 times out of 10.  This q and a are both so succinct.  It's beautiful.
Thank you.